# How to retrieve full list of branches of a GitHub enterprise repository through API

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

I am trying to retrieve a list of branches from Github enterprise using the API.
Currently I am using the `List Branches` API call:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#list-branches

The repository in question has over 100 branches, however through the API only 30 are being returned. Is there any way to retrieve a full list of branches?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason shortly after posting this question.
By default the API responds with 30 branches. by specifying the `per_page` option, the number of branches returned can be specified